# adding a column to data frame based on function

Tags: python, dataframe, function

i have a data frame and i wrote a function that makes some calculates to each row in the df,
i want to add a column to the df that has the calculation i made using the function:

for example from:

| Name | first score | second score | third score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dan | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| David | 3 | 6 | 3 |
| Jennifer | 4 | 5 | 6 |

to:

(adding the "final score" column to the df, the values in the "final score" will present the calculation used the function i wrote for each row)

| Name | first score | second score | third score | Final score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dan | 4 | 3 | 2 | X |
| David | 3 | 6 | 3 | Y |
| Jennifer | 4 | 5 | 6 | Z |

thanks a lot!

Comment: It would convenient if you give the code of the function

Answer (score 0):

[.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is what you'd want to use.

```
df['Final Score'] = df.apply(function, axis=1)
```

setting the axis to 1 tells it to apply the function to each row

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way:

```
df['Final score'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_function(x['first score'], x['second score', x['third score']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df["final score"] = [function('first'), function('second'), function('third')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this:

```
dataframe = [['Dan', 4, 3, 2],
             ['David', 3, 6, 3],
             ['Jennifer', 4, 5, 6]]
```

Then you could do:

```
for person in dataframe:
    person += [0]
```